# React hooks: dispatch action from useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

My folder structure:

```
|--App
  |--Components
    |--PageA.js
    |--PageB.js
    |--PageC.js
  |--common-effects
    |--useFetching.js
```

I am refactoring my code to fetch data from API, using react [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).
I want to dispatch an action from **useEffect** in *useFetching.js* that is intercepted by **saga** middleware. The action should be dispatched only when the components(*PageA*, *PageB*, *PageC*) mount.

I am using **redux**, **react-redux** and **redux-saga**.

*PageA.js*:

```
function(props) {
  useFetching(actionParams)
  //....//
}
```

Similar code for *PageB* and *PageC* components.

I have abstracted the reusable code to fetch data in `useFetching` *Custom hook*.

*useFetching.js*

```
const useFetching = actionArgs => {
  useEffect( () => {
    store.dispatch(action(actionArgs)); // does not work
  })
}
```

I don't know how to access redux `dispatch` in *useFetching*. I tried it with `useReducer` effect, but the sagas missed the action.

Comment: I don't think hooks are meant to be used in arrow functions like that. Also, if you want to use redux they've got hooks for that: https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/pull/1000

Comment: By arrow function do you mean, `const useFetching = actionArgs => {}`, if I am not wrong?

Comment: yeah but looks like i was wrong

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You would need to pass either bound action creators or a reference to `dispatch` to your hook.  These would come from a connected component, same as you would normally use React-Redux:

```js
function MyComponent(props) {
    useFetching(props.fetchSomething);

    return <div>Doing some fetching!</div>
}

const mapDispatch = {
    fetchSomething
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatch)(MyComponent);
```

The hook should then call the bound action creator in the effect, which will dispatch the action accordingly.

Also, note that your current hook will re-run the effect *every* time the component is re-rendered, rather than just the first time.  You'd need to modify the hook like this:

```js
const useFetching = someFetchActionCreator => {
  useEffect( () => {
    someFetchActionCreator();
  }, [])
}
```

Comment: All my components use a single action `export const fetchData = payload => ({ type: 'FETCH_DATA'  })`. `sagas` will then store the value in appropriate reducer of the page by dispatching the corresponding action. According to your solution, I would have to pass reference to dispatch from each component.

Comment: Any action that you want to dispatch, like the `fetchData` function you just wrote in that comment.

Comment: I changed my code accordingly, but still *saga* `yield take('FETCH_DATA');` is not able to intercept this action

Comment: I made some tweaks, it works. Thanks a ton! But I still feel that passing reference to dispatch from every component to custom hook is a bit repeating than what I could in an HOC.

Comment: consider that i don't want connecting action creator to my component specially for my hook. any ideas?

Answer (score 46):

#### Version using react-redux hooks:

You can even cut out the connect function completely by using **`useDispatch`** from react-redux:

```
export default function MyComponent() {
  useFetching(fetchSomething);

  return <div>Doing some fetching!</div>
}
```

with your custom hook

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const useFetching = (someFetchActionCreator) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(someFetchActionCreator());
  }, [])
}
```

**Edit:** removed dispatch from custom hook as suggested by @yonga-springfield

**Note:** React guarantees that dispatch function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect or useCallback dependency list.

Comment: Should `dispatch` be included in the dependency array for useEffect?

Comment: I'm getting an error when puting dispatch in the useEffect:
```React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps```

Comment: @pianoman102 techincaly, yes you should. Even though the note there mentions it's identity is stable and won't change; that doesn't mean yo ushoudl omit it and the lint rule if using CRA will continue to throw.  More context is described here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6880#issuecomment-486640921

Comment: "React guarantees that dispatch function identity is stable" source? I could not find this anywhere.

Comment: @PedroA https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies

Comment: @Martin. Thanks, but what I see there is that `dispatch` **from `useReducer`** is stable, but what about `dispatch` from `useDispatch` from `react-redux`?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56795607/what-are-the-cases-where-redux-dispatch-could-change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56795607/what-are-the-cases-where-redux-dispatch-could-change)

Answer (score 10):

This is just to bring some optimization to @Alex Hans' answer.

As per the documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook). A custom Hook is a JavaScript function whose name starts with ”use” and that may call other Hooks.

With this in mind, we need not send a reference to the dispatch function to the useFetching hook as a parameter but rather, simply not send it and rather simply use it from within the useFetching hook with the appropriate imports.

Here's an excerpt of what I mean.

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const useFetching = (someFetchActionCreator) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(someFetchActionCreator());
    }, [])
}
```

I can't ascertain this example will fit without errors in your codebase in your case but just trying to explain the idea/concept behind this post.

Hope this helps any future comer.

Comment: it is important to pass dependency parameter of dispatch in the useEffect(() => {...}, [dispatch])

Answer (score 8):

Alex Hans right decision with dispatch, but to eliminate request loops to api you can specify the dependence on dispatch ( I used [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide) )

```
  import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
  import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
  import axios from 'axios'
  import { getItemsStart, getItemsSuccess, getItemsFailure } from '../features/itemsSlice'

  const fetchItems = () => async dispatch => {
    try {
      dispatch(getItemsStart());
      const { data } = await axios.get('url/api')
      dispatch(getItemsSuccess(data))
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(getItemsFailure(error))
    }
  }

  const PageA = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { items } = useSelector(state => state.dataSlice)
   
    useEffect(() => {
       dispatch(fetchItems())
    }, [dispatch])

    return (
      <ul>
         {items.map(item => <li>{item.name}</li>}
      </ul> 
    )
  }
  
  export default PageA
```

it is important to passed dependency parameter of dispatch in the useEffect(() => {...}, [dispatch])

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {
   fetchData();
 }, []);

 async function fetchData() {
   try {
     await Auth.currentSession();
     userHasAuthenticated(true);
   } catch (e) {
     if (e !== "No current user") {
       alert(e);
     }
   }
   dispatch(authentication({ type: "SET_AUTHING", payload: false }));
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Consider adding some explanation as to how/why your posted code works.