# What are the cases where Redux dispatch could change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In react-redux v7, we now have the `useDispatch()` hook to get a reference to the store dispatch. See here: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch

The resulting `dispatch` function then needs to be listed as a dependency for any `useEffect`, `useMemo`, etc. hooks. Why is this?

After some testing, the app still works perfectly fine without `dispatch` being listed as a dependency, so I can only assume it's not changing.

Is there any case where the `dispatch` function could change?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There's two answers to this.

First, as far as I know, the React "rules of hooks" ESLint rule knows how to handle the built-in hooks specially.  For example, it knows that `useState()` always returns the same setter function instance, so you don't have to include that in a `useEffect()` dependency array (ditto for the `dispatch` function from a `useReducer()` call).

However, the lint rule *doesn't* know about custom hooks, whether they be from a library or your own.  So, since `useDispatch()` is a custom hook, the lint rule has to assume that whatever this `dispatch` thing is *could* change, and tries to tell you that you need to list it as a dependency.

The second answer is that it's possible to pass a new store reference to `<Provider>`, in which case there's a different `store.dispatch` being returned from the `useDispatch()` hook.

So, realistically, the code will run fine without including `dispatch` in the deps array, because your app is almost definitely using the same store instance the entire time.  But, since the lint rule doesn't know that, you will probably need to include it in the list anyway to make it be quiet.

(Source: I'm a Redux maintainer, and helped guide the implementation of our hooks API :)  )

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation!

Comment: Can't wait for useEffectEvent to be released so we can stop passing dispatch as a deps :)