# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

can anyone help me to get rid of this warning

**React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps**

here is my code

> ```
> function Register(props) {
>   const inusers=useSelector( (state) => {return state});
>   const history=useHistory()
>   const dispatch=useDispatch();
>   // const formik = useFormikContext();
>
>
>   useEffect( () => {
>     dispatch(fetchUser())
>   },[])
> ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix missing dependency warning when using useEffect React Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook)

Answer (score 23):

Just add dispatch among the dependencies:

```
  useEffect(() => {
       dispatch(fetchUser())
  },[dispatch])
```

Dispatch is a safe dependency to add and it won't cause infinite loops.
For more insights on why dispatch can change (and when it can change) check:

[What are the cases where Redux dispatch could change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56795607/what-are-the-cases-where-redux-dispatch-could-change)

**UPDATE:** from react-redux [documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch)

[image: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks]

Comment: When you add dispatch to dependencies array it triggers twice

Comment: @geffting Are you updating the store for some reason? Or do you have any upper render that you are missing? Check carefully, because the docs are clear about it and if you inspect the code of the hook on github (https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/hooks/useDispatch.ts) you can see that dispatch is directly taken from the store.

Answer (score 1):

You can write comment above useEffect dependency `eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` and it will stop complaining.

React guarantees that dispatch function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect or useCallback dependency list.

So its safe to ignore this warning.

```
function Register(props) {
  const inusers=useSelector( (state) => {return state});
  const history=useHistory()
  const dispatch=useDispatch();
  // const formik = useFormikContext();


  useEffect( () => {
    dispatch(fetchUser())

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  },[])
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest simply tell ESLint to ignore the issue. In most cases is not a problem, but if the underlying store changes for any reason it might cause issues

Comment: @AndreaCostanzo1 React guarantees that dispatch function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect or useCallback dependency list.

Comment: we aren't using react use reducer but react-redux use dispatch! As you can see from the source code (https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/hooks/useDispatch.ts) we are returning store.dispatch. What if the underlying store is changed?

Comment: I have updated my post to specify what I'm saying and added a link to the docs

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I don't want to put into the dependency array all the functions defined in other files that can never change anyway, as putting them all in there would obfuscate the real dependencies.