# Redux isn't fetching data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

Couple days ago I posted a question where I had a problem with params to fetch an ID that I needed.

Yesterday I was working with Redux to fetch some data dynamically and I stepped on a problem that the page renders but nos data is displayed (the Redux extension return an empty array) and got an warning on the console saying this

> **React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'dis
> patch' and 'id'. Either include them or remove the dependency arr
> ay  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps**

This is my code:

ProductScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

// Fontawesome
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faAngleLeft } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { detailsProduct } from '../actions/productActions';

function ProductScreen(props) {
    const {id} = useParams();
    //console.log(id)
    //const product = data.products.find(x=> x._id === id);
    const productDetails = useSelector(state => state.productDetails);
    const {product, loading, error} = productDetails;
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(detailsProduct(id));
        return () => {
            //
        };
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="back-to-main">
                <Link to="/"> <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleLeft} /> Back to main page</Link>
            </div>
            {loading? <div>Loading...</div>:
            error? <div>{error}</div>:
            (
                <div className="details">
                    <div className="details-image">
                        <img src={product.image} alt="product"></img>
                    </div>
                    <div className="details-info">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <h4>{product.name}</h4>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                {product.rating} Leafs ({product.numberReviews} Reviews)
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Price: <b>${product.price}</b>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Description:
                                <div>
                                    {product.description}
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div className="details-action">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                Price: {product.price}
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Status: {product.status}
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Qty: <select>
                                    <option>1</option>
                                    <option>2</option>
                                    <option>3</option>
                                    <option>4</option>
                                    <option>5</option>
                                    <option>6</option>
                                    <option>7</option>
                                    <option>8</option>
                                    <option>9</option>
                                    <option>10</option>
                                </select>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <button className="button primary">Add to cart</button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default ProductScreen;
```

server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import data from './data';

const app = express();

app.get("/api/products", (req, res) => {
    res.send(data.products);
});

app.get("/api/products/:id", (req, res) => {
    const productId = req.params.id;
    const product = data.products.find(x=>x._id === productId);
    if(product) 
        res.send();
    else
        res.status(404).send({msg: "Product Not Found."});
});

app.listen(5000, () => {console.log("Server started at http://localhost:5000")});
```

productActions.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import { PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL, PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST, PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS, 
        PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST, PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS 
    } from "../constants/productConstants"

const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST});
        const { data } = await axios.get("/api/products");
    
        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, payload: error.message });   
    }
}

const detailsProduct = (productId) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST, payload: productId });
        const { data } = await axios.get("/api/products/" + productId);
        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    }catch (error){
        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL, payload: error.message })
    }
}

export { listProducts, detailsProduct }
```

productReducer.js

```
import { PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL, PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST, PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
     PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST, PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS 
    } from "../constants/productConstants";

function productListReducer(state= {products:[]}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
            return {loading: true};
        case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return {loading: false, products: action.payload};
        case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
            return {loading: false, error: action.payload}
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

function productDetailsReducer(state= {product: {}}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST:
            return {loading: true};
        case PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
            return {loading: false, product: action.payload};
        case PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL:
            return {loading: false, error: action.payload}
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export { productListReducer, productDetailsReducer }
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { productDetailsReducer, productListReducer } from './reducer/productReducers';


const initialState = {};
const reducer = combineReducers({
    productList: productListReducer,
    productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
})

const composeEnhancers = (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) || compose;

const store = createStore(reducer, initialState, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

export default store;
```

productConstants.js

```
export const PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST = 'PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST';
export const PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS = 'PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS';
export const PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL = 'PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL';

export const PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST = 'PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST';
export const PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS = 'PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS';
export const PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL = 'PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL';
```

I tried to insert the ID parameter on the useEffect function on ProductScreen.js but the dispatch() still shows as an alert/warning.

Where I'm going wrong?

> **PS: Is a e-commerce app**

Comment: This might give the answer for your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54930197/react-hooks-dispatch-action-from-useeffect

Comment: My code is very simmilar to the most up voted answer, specially with the custom hooks. I don't know where is my mistake